# $1-x+x^2-x^3+. . .-x^{17}=a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+. . .+a_{17}y^{17},y=x+1$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

This is a previous AIME question.

> $1-x+x^2-x^3+. . .-x^{17}=a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+. . .+a_{17}y^{17},y=x+1$. Then what is $a_{17}$?

Is anything wrong with the following method?

$1-x+x^2-x^3+. . .-x^{17}=\dfrac{1-x^{18}}{1+x}$

$\implies a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+. . .+a_{17}y^{17}=\dfrac{1-x^{18}}{1+x}$

$\implies a_0+a_1(1+x)+. . .+a_{17}(1+x)^{17}=\dfrac{1-x^{18}}{1+x}$

$\implies a_0(1+x)+a_1(1+x)^2+. . . .a_{17}(1+x)^{18}=1-x^{18}$

Coefficient of $x^{18}$ is $-1$ on the right and $a_{17}$ on the left aide.Therefore,$a_{17}=-1$.Can this method be used to find out any $a_i$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it directly by comparing coefficients of $x^{17}$ in the original

Comment: @Mark,yes!So I basically wasted much time doing redundant things.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method is that we can ignore other terms except $a_{17}y^{17}=a_{17}(x+1)^{17}$, because this is the only term that is possible to product the term $-x^{17}$.

$(x+1)^{17}=\sum_{n=0}^{17}C_{17}^nx^{17-n}$(Binomial theorem), then the coefficient of $x^{17}$ is $C_{17}^0=1$, and the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the right side is $a_{17}C_{17}^0=a_{17}$.

Left=rigtht, so $a_{17}=-1$.

Your method is also right.

Comment: Thank you.My method is indeed right,but it doesn't help solve this problem very efficiently.But if,say the question wanted us to find $a_{2}$ as the original question does,could my method work?

Comment: I am not sure that your method works well to find $a_2$, I think there will be a big group of equation about $a_i,i\in [0,17]$ and $i$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The binomial theorem says
$$
\begin{align}
1-x+x^2-\dots-x^{17}
&=\frac{1-x^{18}}{1+x}\\
&=\frac{1-(y-1)^{18}}{y}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{18}\binom{18}{k}(-1)^{k-1}y^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{18}{k+1}(-1)^ky^k
\end{align}
$$
Look at the $k=17$ term.

---

The method in the question *can* be used to find any of the $a_k$, but it will involve solving $18-k$ simultaneous equations. The equation from the question is
$$
a_0(1+x)+a_1(1+x)^2+. . . .a_{17}(1+x)^{18}=1-x^{18}
$$
Therefore, looking at the coefficients of the powers of $x$:
$$
\begin{align}
x^{18}:&\binom{18}{18}a_{17}=-1\\
x^{17}:&\binom{18}{17}a_{17}+\binom{17}{17}a_{16}=0\\
x^{16}:&\binom{18}{16}a_{17}+\binom{17}{16}a_{16}+\binom{16}{16}a_{15}=0\\
\vdots&\\
x^1:&\binom{18}{1}a_{17}+\binom{17}{1}a_{16}+\binom{16}{1}a_{15}+\dots+\binom{1}{1}a_0=0
\end{align}
$$
There is one more equation, but it is dependent on the previous ones:
$$
x^0:\ \binom{18}{0}a_{17}+\binom{17}{0}a_{16}+\binom{16}{0}a_{15}+\dots+\binom{1}{0}a_0=1
$$
The efficiency of this method is a subjective matter.

Comment: I do indeed know the original solution(sorry I should have added that to the body of my question),but I wanted to know if my method can be used to compute any $a_i$.

Comment: @rah4927: To compute $a_i$ using your method, it appears that you would need to solve a set of $18-i$ linear equations. It can be done, but I don't know if one would call it efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Let's let LHS = $1-x+x^2..$.  We seek to find $a_0+a_1y+a_2^2+\dots$, where $y=x+1$.

Since the only one term that have $y^{17}$, this is equal to the term with $x^{17}$, that is $-1$.

The answer with $-18$ is due to the reversal of the equation.  It's actually $a^0$ that gives 18, and $a^n$ gives $^{18}P_{n+1}$, ie 18, -153, 816, -...